# Remove/ make transparent the discarded area in openGL

Tags: opengl, transparency, fragment-shader, opentk

When I remove some bottom portion of my image using discard of opengl, that discarded area is showing with the color I specified in clearcolor. How can i make this clearcolor transparent, or is there any other way to hide those discarded portion?

I'm using below code when texture loads.

```
        GL.ClearColor(new Color4(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f));
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        TexUtil.InitTexturing();
        GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);

        GL.ColorMaterial(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, ColorMaterialParameter.AmbientAndDiffuse);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

        GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0); // render per default onto screen, not some FBO
```

Fragment code:

```c
if( vTexCoord.y>1.0-sVerticalCropVal  )
{discard;
} 
vec4 color = texture2D (sTexture_2, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
gl_FragColor =color;
```

Comment: When you discard a fragment, it is not drawn at all. So you see the clearcolor instead, because the clearcolor is the color which is used to initialize your buffer. You have to draw a fragment to see anything different from the clearcolor. If you want transparency effects, you have to draw a certain fragment at least twice

Comment: Please see my Fragment shader code. Could you please explain how to do this - "You have to draw a fragment to see anything different from the clearcolor."

Comment: @nsds I think you did not understand the comment. If you `discard` a fragment, the fragment is "not drawn" and the  framebuffer is not changed. Hence you can see what was previously in the framebuffer. In your case, this is the clear color. If you want to achieve a transparent window, this is not how you can do it.

Comment: If you want a transparent window on Windows, I might link to an appropiate answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Could you give me any idea or  link to refer for transparent windows in glcontrol